# Using Identity Server 4 with OIDC External Provider is not mapping the claims

Tags: external, identityserver4, claims, openid-connect

I'm using Identity Server 4. I have an external identity provider that I want to get the claims from the id token. In the documentation, http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signin_external_providers.html, it says that all the claims will be available. When I sign in only a few claims are shown in the Home/secure page. If I goto the Diagnostics page and look at the Id Token, they are there. I would like to include some of the claims in the id token and access token that the service is returning. I have created a Profile service thinking that I could add them there, but the same claims that show in the home/secure page are the only ones available:

Here is my external config in start up:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddOpenIdConnect("external", "external", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;

                options.Authority = "https://external idp address.com";
                options.ClientId = "secret";

                options.Scope.Clear();
                options.Scope.Add("openid profile");

                options.SaveTokens = true;

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name"
                };

                options.ClaimActions.MapAll();
            });
```

Comment: What flow are you using? And did you explicitly specified 'AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true' for your client?

Comment: Or you can use client side configuration 'options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true'.

Comment: Yes, I've done both of these suggestions. I got around it by adding code to the ExternalController in the Quickstart and manually adding them. But I think the settings suggested should just work.